# Why is «Какого цвета» in genitive case?

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, падежи, родительный-падеж, синтаксис

I came across the sentence *«Какого цвета платье?»* today. I would've assumed that «Какого цвета» would be in the nominative case and was confused to see this construction. Is there a grammatical rule/logic behind this, or is it just another case of "they just say it this way, so learn it".

Comment: Cases and the very they are governed by are supposed to be memorised in any language. Cases in foreign language seem plausible to someone only if in their native language one can find parallels.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nominative doesn't work for the same reason it doesn't work in this English statement:

- *The dress is red colour.

But we can make it work using 'of':

- The dress is of red colour.

I don't know why English loses the 'of' when the statement is converted into a question:

- What colour is this dress?

Other languages keep it:

- **De** quelle couleur est cette robe?
- **Di** che colore è questo vestito?

So it's English that's the odd one out. Russian is logical. :)

Comment: Spanish, being also a Romance language, follows exactly the same pattern, but yet another Romance language, Romanian, does drop the “de” in the question.

Comment: @RomanOdaisky - In Romanian “ce culoare?” (what color?) is in the Nominative-Accusative case because the verb “to have” is used while talking about colors, “to _have_ a color” rather than “to be of a color”: “Ce culoare _are_ rochia?” (What color _has_ the.dress?) The same in German: “Welche Farbe _hat_ das Kleid?” – here “welche Farbe” is the Accusative case.

Comment: @YellowSky _Ce culoare este_ is also a thing in Romanian, which does not mirror the declarative _a fi **de** culoare X._

Comment: @RomanOdaisky - _**De** ce culoare este X?_ is also a thing in Romanian, which does mirror the declarative _a fi **de** culoare X_: [Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1IHCB_enUA879UA879&sxsrf=ALeKk029oY2LSNS26ZOcXrpfwFJxjygR1w%3A1598673364245&ei=1NFJX-XADp2Wjgbv4Y64Bw&q=%22de+ce+culoare+este%3F%22&oq=%22de+ce+culoare+este%3F%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoKCCMQrgIQsAMQJ1CucViucWCKd2gAcAB4AIAB2gGIAfcCkgEFMC4xLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjl-vKvwr_rAhUdi8MKHe-wA3cQ4dUDCA0&uact=5).

Comment: @YellowSky Interesting

Answer (score 5):

In Russian, the question about the color of the dress has at least 3 possible answers:

```
(1) Платье красное. ~ Красное платье.  
(2) Платье красного цвета. ~ Красного цвета платье.
(3) Цвет платья – красный. ~ Красный цвет платья.
```

Now let us see how we construct a question to get an answer of type (1), and how we do it for types (2) and (3).

In (1) *красное* is a Nominative case singular neuter gender qualitative adjective, so in our question we will need the question word *какой?* in the same form (Nom. sg. n.) — *какое?*

> – *Какое* платье?
> – *Красное* платье.

However, *какой?* can stand for any kind of a qualitative adjective, not only for a color, but also for size, length, age, price, etc., which means that instead of an answer about the color of the dress we can well get answers about its other qualities, e. g. *Длинное платье. Новое платье. Красивое платье. Дорогое платье.*

To make sure the answer will be exactly about the *color* of the dress, we must use the word *цвет* “color” in the question, which means type (2) answer will be expected. In (2), *красный цвет* “red color” is an attribute of *платье*, that is why the noun phrase *красного цвета* is in the **Genitive case**, in the case of an attribute. To make a question, *красного* is substituted for *какой?*, but this time in **Gen**. sg. n. — *какого?* (**of what color** [is] dress?):

> – *Какого цвета* платье?
> – *Красного цвета* платье.

*Красное платье* ~ *Платье красное* (adjective in the Nom. case) can also be an answer to that question.

When we need an answer of type (3), a questions about color can be asked with *какой цвет?*, Nominative. This time *цвет* is the head of the noun phrase and *платье* is its attribute in Genitive (what [is] color **of dress**?):

> – *Какой цвет* платья?
> – *Красный цвет* платья.

Irrespective of which of the types you choose, you **cannot** have both *какой цвет?* and *платье* in the Nominative case, one of them has got to be put in Genitive.

Answer (score 1):

Sergey Slepov's answer is correct (though I'm not agree with languages weird-shaming).

Note also that Russian doesn't use the verb **have** too much.

So this construction is less usual for Russian:

> The dress **has** this color. `ACC`

While this one is more usual:

> The dress **is of** this color. `GEN`

And that's why the question is also in `GEN`.

Comment: English has no cases, no NOM, no GEN, none at all.

Comment: I would say English has no declentions (except for pronouns and possessive). But the words still have their roles it text.

Comment: If you mean roles, why do you use the names of cases for that? In “The dress has this color” the role of “this color” is direct object, why did you choose “NOM” as a label for this role? Direct objects and “NOM” have nothing in common.

Comment: You are right, changed to ACC.